# Difference between usart and modem

Tags: wireless, uart, rs232, digital-communications

This is a question of entrance exam for government telecommunications company:

> A complex device used to send and receive serial data over telephone lines is
>
> A)USART
>
> B)Modem
>
> C)SDLC
>
> D)RS232

The given was USART, but according to me, it is modem that we use over telephone lines. What would be the justification to USART if it is the correct answer?

Comment: Whoever wrote that question needs taking out back and giving a good kicking.

Comment: also c) shud be SDLC a sync. data link controller

Comment: Before trying answering such questions, you should read it several times, and think directly and by contradiction. Question is actually very good.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't say that a USART is a complex device.

Comment: I agree its not that complex, but is compared to a level shifting inverter (TTL to RS-232) it was called a VLSI chip when they came out. It's all relative... Einstein.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, I'd say that an USART is quite simple compared to a modern **modem** :D  So in the scope of the question: of those four choices, USART is not particlylarly complex... :D

Comment: I know it relatively simple.  I designed a UART on a board with simple CMOS logic  in 1976. Perhaps they should change to question to make a block diagram of each of the following items a,b,c,d

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The modem actually sends **parallel** (2 or more) bits of data with trellis coding and 4, 64 to 128 level constellation of  phase & amplitude modulation and NOT SERIAL data.

**So USART is the correct answer.**

- USART uses logic to send serial data with an RS-232 a level shifter, then is modulated by one MODem and DEModulated by another modem in both directions.
- the MODEM sends ANALOG signals converted to fit 56kbps into < 4kHz of audio bandwidth  using up to 64 QPSK levels to modulate the data with channel equalization and single echo cancelling but contains synchronous QPSK up to 64 level ASK/PSK  with no start/stop bits

**So the USART sends the SERIAL DATA**

**Trick question due to "wording"** because the MODEM is most complex with analog modulation but the USART communicates with **logical serial data.**

(opinions)

The USART is trivial by comparison which does 16x clock sync on start edge and can be easily monitored. (once upon a time) I designed a UART and I know it was simple for me at the time before USARTs even existed. circa mid 70's

> EDIT ( is it too late?)

- From the telephone line perspective the MODEM sends(& receives) the data.
- From the User perspective, the USART sends the data (& receives) the data.

  - all three answers a,b,d are need to make it work
- Since each answer has two interfaces, there is ambiguity ( its bad enough we mix up Send and Receive for the same wire.
- but the **keyword "over the phone lines"** applies only to the MODEM , which is also **most** complex of all choices, so perhaps from the POTS or PSTN perspective could be the better answer, even though the signals cannot be decoded in many cases ( would not have may not same delay equalization and handshaking cannot be done)  In many ways its like scrambling ,which is why it always sounds like white noise.

**I concede both a) & b) can be correct**, in this shamelessly ambiguous question.

Logical Explanation

All communication channels have two (2) sides in the OSI model TO and FROM both sides and also in both directions.(Rx,Tx)

- The modem has two ports; a serial RS 232 port and an analog PSTN port
- The USART has a parallel port and a serial TTL port.
- All serial ports send and receive serial data.
- Therefore both the USART and MODEM share this complex function

  - when sending data over the phone line as they each have a serial port, albeit different types as TTL logic serial data is inverted with respect to the RS-232 bipolar data, in spite of having the same logic threshold.
  - but there was no stipulation or implied statement saying which type of serial port.
  - there was also no specific perspective who is responsible for sending the data. The Modem is just a medium used on the phone lines.

    > - therefore a) & b) can be correct since there are acceptable ambiguous perspectives.

Comment: Sir what should be the answer according to you.The above key is a provisional one.We have to send them the proof if its the wrong answer.So if the answer is Modem how can it be justified any supporting links or documents that can help me claim my answer

Comment: The key words in the question are "serial data" hence UART or USART is correct. Modem is not Serial , per se and the others are wrong for other reasons. the phone line is irrelevant, hence trick question

Comment: A USART is more complex and can generate data in a form corresponding to many different standard protocols such as IrDA, LIN, Smart Card, Driver Enable for RS-485 interfaces, and Modbus, to name a few. A USART also has the same asynchronous capabilities as a UART, using RS-232 to a modem,, so again phone line is irrelevant

Comment: I don't think we can deny that a modem sends serial data, even if, in fact, it does it 2 bits at a time. That's almost a detail and I don't think this question tricks the students like that. And the thing is: a UART is not enough to send data over a *phone* line. How do you connect both TX and RX over a single pair? So UART can't be the answer either. You need a modem, after the UART. *That* is the point the question is meant to make.

Comment: IMHO, a modem *does* send and receive serial data. For example, a tabletop modem takes serial data from an RS-232 connector, sends it, somehow, to the phone line. Also it receives data, somehow, from a phone line and it gives out that received data serially, in another pin of the RS-232 connector.

Answer (score 5):

My opinion is that right answer is modem. Read question carefully:

> A complex device used to send and receive serial data overtelephone lines is

It has specific conditions set:

- device
- serial data
- telephone lines

USART can not be connected to telephone line directly. RS232 is not a device. SDLC is not a device.

Only modem choice satisfies all three.

Comment: Yet a modem is totally incapable of sending any data on its own and knows nothing about the data m the content or the format. It just provides the "carrier" whereas only the USART is capable of sending and receiving data, regardless of the medium which can be irrelevant to the end user.

Comment: Question does not constraint that device should be able to *send on its own*. Question says *used to send*. USART also can not send meaningful data by itself without computer providing this data to it to send.

Comment: you cannot deny, there is ambiguity in perspective

Answer (score 2):

"USART" is... a poor choice for an answer. Transmitting data over the PSTN *requires* adaptive MOdulation and DEModulation, which are the jobs of a modem. A USART can be used to transmit the data to the modem, but ultimately without the modem the transmission is limited to local equipment.

Comment: This is indeed a horrible question.  But actually, a USART (or UART or less universal equivalent) is what is absolutely required.  A Modem is *usual* but is only required if the lines are limited in bandwidth as those not electrically dedicated would be, and also traditionally where electrical properties of the line were handled.  But you could go buy a spool of phone wire and connect two UARTS.  You cannot get anywhere with modems without a data serializer (though some have that built in).

Comment: @ChrisStratton: What you have written isn't wrong, but the question specifically says "serial data" and "telephone lines". The former implies that the data is already in some serial encoding, whereas the latter implies SS5 or newer rather than just bare wires.

Comment: This is a question of entrance exam for government telecommunications company.So what should the answer be accordingly?

Comment: We all know telecoms are just *horrible* for customers. Such entrance exam questions give the answer **why**.